# Objective C send JSON to Symfony2 Server

Tags: php, objective-c, json, http, symfony

I have an Objective C project from which I need to send JSON data to a Symfony2 php server.

This is very normal and I have read many documents and previous issues in Stackoverflow, and I think my code is correct. But for some reason, I am not getting the data in the server as I think it should.

Let me show you two different versions of the code and consequences (in both examples, a `NSMutableURLRequest *request` variable is supposedly well declared:

After setting all http heading, I do this:

```
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hist_id=%d", 10];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

And once sent to the server, the complete Request value has the following:

```
POST /~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app.php/api/apiGetQuestions HTTP/1.1
Accept:               */*
Accept-Encoding:      gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:      en-us
Connection:           keep-alive
Content-Length:       10
Content-Type:         application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:               PHPSESSID=8915n9cj4ak8fjna4emvnrsov5
Host:                 127.0.0.1
Surrogate-Capability: symfony2="ESI/1.0"
User-Agent:           PreparaTest/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/12.4.0
X-Php-Ob-Level:       1

hist_id=10 [] []   // <-- TAKE A LOOK AT THE BODY CONTENT
```

And if I do in the PHP `$hist_id = $this->getRequest()->get('hist_id')` I properly get a 10.

**All perfect so far!**

But what if I need to send to the server a more complex set of data. For example an NSDictionary with, for example, some array among its values. In this case, better use JSON, yes?

This is the code and the consequence for this second case. Note that in this second example I won't use dictionaries and arrays, but just a simple dictionary with that same 'hist_id' value. So we can parallelize both examples.

```
// Create an array with a dictionary with a unique "hist_id" value set to 10
// (just like before, but using a dictionary and converting it to JSON.
NSDictionary *postDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 10], @"hist_id",
                          nil];

// Convert it to json string
NSString *json = [postDictionary JSONRepresentation]; // This is perfectly performed!

// Convert to NSData the json with the dictionary
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[json UTF8String] length:[json length]];

// Set headers and the body to the request
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
```

Once sent to the server, unluckily, I am not getting propperly the request in the server side:

```
POST /~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app.php/api/saveTest HTTP/1.1
Accept:               application/json
Accept-Encoding:      gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:      en-us
Connection:           keep-alive
Content-Length:       15
Content-Type:         application/json
Cookie:               PHPSESSID=caihkf98lh8injmdju512fvbc7
Host:                 127.0.0.1
Surrogate-Capability: symfony2="ESI/1.0"
User-Agent:           PreparaTest/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/12.4.0
X-Php-Ob-Level:       1

{"hist_id":"10"} [] [] // <-- TAKE A LOOK AT THE BODY CONTENT AND COMPARE WITH THE ABOVE EXAMPLE!!
```

Apparently it is all right, but when I go `$this->getRequest()->get('hist_id')`, I don't get any value.

The only thing I can do to get the content is:

```
$content = json_decode($request->getContent());
$hist_id = $content->{'hist_id'};
```

Is this the correct approach? Isn't there any possibility to get the 'hist_id' value just doing a `$this->getRequest()->get('hist_id');` when sending all via JSON? Ok, I can work with json_decode, but I'd rather prefer not to use it as my application is supposed to be multichannel and when I send the data from the web (JQuery.post), the content is automatically converted to php data structures. I wouldn't like to use different code for the API depending on "who" is asking for the information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a category to generate the JSON data to be sent to the server in these two lines of code:

```
// Convert it to json string
NSString *json = [postDictionary JSONRepresentation]; // This is perfectly performed!

// Convert to NSData the json with the dictionary
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[json UTF8String] length:[json length]];
```

Try replacing it with the NSJSONSerialization and see if that makes a difference. At the very least you will remove the need to convert it to an NSString. It might be that the category is doing something funky.

```
NSData* requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

If you want to see if it's generating the correct JSON you can print it out using:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:requestData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As soon as I get home, I'll try what you say. Nevertheless, I don't think that the problem is in the generation of the json string, as it is doing perfectly (even the complex linked dictionaries and arrays). And, in fact, I have already tried with other serialization methods. I'll tell you asap.

Comment: Yep. Definitely, once re-readed, I did this yesterday and didn't get anything diferent. Anyway I'll try is as soon as I get home, but I am not very hopeful on it :(. Thanks a lot again! :)

Comment: Confirmated. Once at home I have tried what you said and data keeps getting the server and the request in the plain json text, with no conversion to PHP structures. I am starting to think that this is the correct way and I am obligated to use the json_decode function